# Website not resizing properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the problem that my website is resizing correctly when I change the viewport in chrome or go to it directly on my phone.

It does work however when i just resize my browser window.

This is the website http://maxehlers.com/test/ if you would like to try it out.

Most stuff on the website is set up with percentages for with and height.

How can i make the website act responsively when accessing it from a mobile device? Do I have to add media queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing the viewpoint meta tag

here are the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` should sort it.

There is more good info here on [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) on resposive tags

Comment: Also, sometimes it is just a random bug for Chrome. Try to close the tab, and re-open it, and it should work.